# Crash when object deallocated while running a background thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have a set of objects, init'd and owned by a view controller. The view controller starts a `fetchData` method in each of these objects, which runs in a background thread and then, when it's done, returns the main thread and changes a property - `self.dataFetchComplete`, which the view controller is observing.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        
    self.dataFetchComplete = YES;
});
```

If the view controller is deallocated before these objects are finished with this method, when it hits the `self.dataFetchComplete = YES;` line, it crashes.

How can i stop it from crashing when trying to change this property after being deallocated.

EDIT: More info, and clarity.

Comment: You need to provide more context and code. If your objects are being deallocated prematurely (and you **know** it happens on purpose), then you are having a bad design problem.

Comment: Please clarify "If the object is deallocated before it gets back onto the main queue, it throws an error when trying to set this property." Too many pronouns. What object? Before what gets back? What throws error? Are you using ARC?

Comment: The block should be capturing (and retaining) self, so if it's being deallocated you have a bug elsewhere that's overreleasing it.

Comment: You can't rely on an autorelease pool in another thread not draining... it could very well do that before you are done with an object, to transfer ownership to your pool you can throw in a `[[obj retain] autorelease]`

Answer (score 1):

That block has a strong reference to `self`.  The only way `self` could be deallocated is if you are over-releasing it elsewhere (as @Catfish_Man indicated).

1. if you have a crash, post the backtrace of the crash
2. if you have an over-release crash, use Instruments to track all retain/release events on the object.
3. run the analyzer and fix any problems it indicates.